# Rails table display and database design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have two tables, `Beacon belongs to Category` and `Category has many beacons`, in beacon table, I add a `foreign key: category_id`, but when i want display in table, i need the `category_name` in the category table, now I use a stupid way as following:

```
...
<% @beacons.each do |beacon| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= beacon.beacon_uuid %></td>
              <% @category_name = Category.find(beacon.category_id).category_name %>
              <td><%= @category_name %></td>
...
```

but when beacon data get bigger, request get bigger, how to change my code to defence this stupid question?can someone give me some suggestion or reference? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to an N+1 query, wherein the number of queries executed is equal to the number of beacons + 1.  If so, your queries look similar those below.

```
select beacons.* from beacons;
select categories.* from categories where categories.id = 1;
select categories.* from categories where categories.id = 2;
select categories.* from categories where categories.id = 3;
```

Assuming your beacon model has the `belongs_to :category` relation declared, this can be avoided by using `includes` to eager load the association in the controller

```
def index
  @beacons = Beacon.all.includes(:category)
end
```

The view can then be changed to take advantage of this, instead of pulling a fresh copy of the category from the database for each beacon

```
<%= beacon.category.category_name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper of the category and its attributes in the beacon itself.

In Rails, you can go both ways:

`Category.beacons` will return an array of all the beacons the category has and their attributes
`Beacon.category`  will return the attributes of its category.

Following the same logic, you just need this:

```
  <%= beacon.category.category_name %>
```

Comment: Thanks...I tried, but in this case, when I have 10 beacon, it's still send 10 request to get category_name, this way is more clearly than before, but do the same thing... can I use only 1 request to get what I want?